# Azure Data Factory: Copy activity - Writing to sink is showing '00:00:00'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I build a pipeline in which the Copy activity is loading a flat file into a SQL table.

When I view the activity details, the **Writing to sink** is always showing '00:00:00'.

[image]

Has anyone ever seen the same issue or it is just me?

Comment: Why did you considered it as an issue?  If the flat file is not very large and according the Data Factory performance, it could take less than 1s.

Comment: Hi Thuc Ngugen, you could tested with some large file to check the Writing to sink time. Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: In our case, the biggest file is still less than 50Mb. So I'm not still if that is considered large file.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I think this is because your data volume is not big enough, and you just do a copy without data analytis. So that is why is takes less than one second.

Comment: This is something I have a problem with understanding. 
As you can see in my image, the total duration for *Transfer* is 13 seconds, in which 'Listing source' and 'Reading from source' have taken 4 seconds. 
Where has the remaining 9 seconds gone?